# Skyscanner API: Cannot create session via Flights Live Pricing

Tags: api, session, skyscanner, rate-limiting

I'm exactly following [this API guide](https://skyscanner.github.io/slate/#creating-the-session) via `curl` but yet keep getting this messages:

> {"ValidationErrors":[{"Message":"Rate limit has been exceeded: 0
>   PerMinute for PricingSession"}]}

I'm new there and i'm sure i have never pulled before. Therefore, there's no way i could have "exceeded" the rate.

Please let me know why and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like their hotel and Flight's live pricing API are down at the moment, as per their documentation. 
I am getting the same error as

Comment: Yea i also noticed that. So that all our business (i mean: services) will be down, just like that?

Comment: https://support.business.skyscanner.net/hc/en-us/articles/206800359-Which-services-can-I-access-and-what-are-the-rate-limits- 

_Please note that access to our Hotels API and **Flights Live Pricing service are currently suspended**. Unfortunately we are unable to give a date for when these services will be re-launched, but please check back regularly for updates._